# Please help me identify the specifics on my older Giant Sedona?

Tags: identify-this-bike, giant

I was generously given this working, older Giant Sedona. I have searched and searched, high and low to find out specifics on the bike, to no avail. I've been to Giant Bicycles website, there's no info available about older bikes and you can't register an older bike either. I have been to Bikepedia, again no specifics about my bike. bikeindex.org, it was never registered there as stolen. I have google searched "giant sedona" and have looked at images for hours trying to identify specifics on my bike. I have spent hours reading links and pages and pages of posts about identifying bikes. It would be neat if Giant or someone would create a site that one could plug in the serial number and find info about a specific bike. I'm surprised no one has done that yet. Nonetheless, if anyone has any useful tips I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You say 'specifics', what do you want to know about it exactly? Exact model, year of manufacture?

Comment: What do you want to know?  It's a bike.  Looks like maybe 18 speeds.  Canti brakes.

Comment: I'd estimate its a 90s MTB back when suspension was known to be optional.  It would make a fantastic commuter if you swap in slick 26" tyres and optionally fit mudguards/fenders for the wet days, and lights for the night/dark times.

Comment: Yes Argenti Apparatus. Specifics. Year made, exact model those are specifics.

Comment: The reason we are asking exactly what you want to know is this site is geared towards concrete questions and answers. We mean no offense by asking for clarification.

Comment: It will be hard to determine exact year. Cantilever brake calipers mean it's most likely prior to 1996. If you post a close up picture of the rear derailleur  the groupset model may be identified which would help marrow down the year.

Comment: It's a very generic bike.  Giant is a pretty good brand (or was, back then) and it appears to be in good condition.  If you're wondering if it's worth much, no.  You might be able to sell it for $10-25 in a garage sale.

Answer (score 7):

This is a 1996 Giant Sedona. I had this exact bike, right down to the color.
The frame is 4130 cro mo and the tubes are 'triple butted'. If you notice the top tube and down tube are flared at the joints.  The was the 'external butting' and they were also butted for tube wall thickness internally.
The groupset was entirely shimano STX, which, at the price point (about $600 CAD at the time) represented an amazing value.  7 speed rapid-fire shifters, panaracer smoke and dart tires, non descript black quill stem, giant branded aluminum bar, saddle and grips (which were thin and hard, but after a while I got so used to them that any other grips felt mushy).
I can't recall the rim manufacturer and model, but they were 36 spoke....a great bike, and if you still have it, I'd be tempted to offer to buy it, strictly for nostalgic purposes....

Answer (score 2):

I can see a sticker on the seat tube - which might be the Giant size sticker but if it is a bike shop sticker you can call them and there is a chance they will have the serial number

In terms of registries that is a no-go. There is no single national bike registry.  It varies by geographic region or jurisdiction, most places going away from registering bicycles in the nineties or earlier.

The other thing is about the only thing a bicycle "manufacturer" builds is the frame.  Giant buys the rest of everything else from a third party - especially things like wheels and shifters are made by Shimano, and a bunch of other wheel makers.

its not a bad bike, its an inexpensive one, that any shop will know how to work on.  I would just appreciate the working wheels

Answer (score 1):

This is a early 90s, maybe 1992 Giant Sedona Base model. There were cooler paint jobs on versions like the ATX. That being said as far as specs I can tell you that you most likely dont have a lot of the original parts on this frame.
In the later 90's they moved to having shock absorbing seat posts, and different styles of brakes. After that in the late 90s the started offering forks with shocks.
What are the specifics that you are looking for? 
You should be able to identify the components by sight and markings. count your gears. Wheels look pretty basic 26", tires the same.