# Giant Sedona with elliptical crank

Tags: giant

I am trying to determine the model suffix and yr for my giant Sedona. It has an elliptical crank, no seat tube shock, and no front fork shock. It was made in Taiwan, the frame that is, it is an 18-speed, chromalloy and quad-butted, cantilever brakes and 1.95x26 Pathfinder tires which may not be the original. I think it is somewhere around mid or early 90s? I bought it used about 1996 from a bike shop who had a contract with the local city police who used it for a city cruiser. The bike shop rebuilt it and sold it to me.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve?  The description above includes mostly components that are easily and inexpensively replaceable, leaving nothing to go on.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is another Stack Exchange question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51893/please-help-me-identify-the-specifics-on-my-older-giant-sedona) which may shed some light on your model of Giant.  I suggest to keep perusing the internet via a search engine with something like "early 1990's Giant Sedona" as a query.

The best way to match up your bike to a specific year and model is to compare frame material (steel, aluminum, carbon, etc.), paint schemes and componentry, keeping in mind both of those latter aspects can be readily changed by another owner.

Here's a few references online:

[Bike Pedia](https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?item=42025)

[Bicycle Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/)

[BBB-Giant bicycles](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/family/683/)

[Restoration Bike--Giant catalogs](https://www.restoration.bike/bike-catalogs/giant-catalogs/)

Hope you find what you're looking for!